# Замена ключевых слов в тексте

Tags: python, строки

Есть код, выводящий текст из "текстовых блоков". Как заменить слова, заключённые в символы процента (%user_name%, %city_name%) и после вывести всё это на экран?

```
##b1-start
Hello %user_name%!
You are in %city_name%!
##b1-end
```

Я пробовал так:

```
key = input('key> ')

with open('data.dat','r',encoding='utf-8') as data:
   for line in data:
       if line.rstrip() == '##%s-start' % key:
        line.replace('##%s-start' % key,'')
        break

   for line in data:
       if line.rstrip() == '%user_name%':
           line.replace('%user_name%','Joe')

   for line in data:
       if line.rstrip() == '##%s-end' % key:
           line.replace('##%s-end' % key,'')
           break

       for i in range(len(line)):
           print(line[i],end='')
           time.sleep(.05)
```

Если же убрать часть с поиском ключевых слов, то текст выводится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете проходить циклом по объекту файла несколько раз (по аналогии с итераторами). Цикла достаточно одного:

```
# создаем набор замен
setpatt = dict((
                 ('%user_name%', 'Joe'),
                 ('%city_name%', 'NY'),
              ))


def myreplacer(line):

    for patt in setpatt:
        if line.count(patt):
            print(line.replace(patt, setpatt[patt]))
            break

key = input('key> ')
with open('data.dat', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data:

    for line in data:
       # ловим входной блок
       if line.rstrip() == '##%s-start' % key:
           # с расчетом на неизвестное количество строк с заменой
           while True:
               # получаем следующую строку
               _line = data.readline().rstrip()
               # если эта строка - конец блока - выходим из вложенного цикла искать следующий блок по ключу `key`
               if _line == '##%s-end' % key:
                   break
               # если в троке есть один из шаблонов, выводим строку с заменой шаблона
               # UPD проверка и вывод в функции
               myreplacer(_line)
               #elif _line.count('%user_name%'):
                   #print(_line.replace('%user_name%', 'Joe'))
               #elif _line.count('%city_name%'):
                   #print(_line.replace('%city_name%', 'NY'))
```

Comment: А как можно избавиться от проверки через условные операторы в поиске шаблонов? К примеру, сравнивать их из списка?

Comment: @CockLobster, посмотрите обновленный код. Через функцию и набор шаблонов удобнее всего, вроде бы.